# input text type zoomed in on iOS

Tags: ios, css, mobile, input, mobile-safari

I'm having a weird issue with a input text type on iOS safari.

When I tap on the text input and the keyboard screen apperas, the website gets zoomed in and after I tap done it doesn't go back.

**Here is how it looks before the tap.**

[image]

**How it looks after the tap:**

[image]

Any ideas how can I solve this? Is there a trick or something to disable this zoom?

Comment: Did you try 16px font size?

Answer (score 1):

If you set your font size to 16px it wont zoom any more.

You may also want to use an IOS media query with that.